# OpenCart 1.5.5.1 Custom URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, opencart

I need help in rewriting these three types of Custom URL's via `OpenCart Seo_Url` functionality or via custom rules inside `.htaccess` file.

---

### URL type #1 is:

`example.com/index.php?route=estore/signup`

### Ideal URL for the above URL type #1 is:

`example.com/estore-signup`

---

### URL type # 2

`example.com/index.php?route=estore/store&store_id=3`

### Ideal URL for the above URL type #2 is:

`example.com/estore/canon-seo-keyword`

---

### URL type # 3

`example.com/index.php?route=estore/product&store_id=3&product_id=84`

### Ideal URL for the above URL type #3 is:

`example.com/estore/products/canon-seo-keyword/product-seo-keyword`

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you enable seo url in admin side? I think at least the 3rd one should work after enabling seo.

Comment: Yes, I ave enabled the Seo URLs from Admin side.

Comment: But the built-in functionality of OpenCart does not work on my custom `estore` pages.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should change your https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php file and https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/url.php file for basicly solution. You should create a rules for all the links.

For example, product page link should be

```
[BASE_URL]/[STORE_NAME]/[MANUFACTURER_SEO]/[product_SEO] => product page
[BASE_URL]/[STORE_NAME]/[MANUFACTURER_SEO] => manufaturer page
[BASE_URL]/[STORE_NAME]/[CATEGORY_SEO] => category page
[BASE_URL]/[STORE_NAME]/[CATEGORY_SEO]/[CATEGORY_SEO] => sub category page

...etc.
```

After that, you should implement them in https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php file.

On the other hand, you can chage you `url_alias` data when the elements save. For example, opencart save the product or categories seo keywords as `ipod-classic`,... etc. You can save all like what you want, `apple/ipod/classic`. And change your https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php file and continue.